# CSP Block all script and images from jquery and AWS S3

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I built an ExpressJS App and I deployed it on Heroku.

But My images won't load and the script does not work...

Here are two of the errors in my console log :

Refused to load https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Refused to load https://bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/log.png because it does not appear in the "img-src" directive of the Content Security Policy.

I tried to add a  tag with change for CSP, I tried to change CSP with a set header, but I think that doesn't work and there is something that blocked my change for CSP...

Please help me!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `img-src` directive. For instance, I'm using [`helmet`](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet), and in my Express `server.js`, I have the following:

```
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
                'img-src': ["'self'", 'https://bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com'],
            },
        }),
    );
```